# MongoDB-Community not starting on Mac and giving errors

Tags: mongodb, macos, homebrew

I am writing to inform that i had installed mongodb-community some time back using brew (High Sierra) and it was running. Then recently i upgraded and it doesn't seem to wire up. When i am running mongo in terminal, I am getting error:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.4.0
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:362:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

When i checked logs for starting the mongodb-community service, I am getting following error:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-04T21:01:35.015-07:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20698,   "ctx":"main","msg":"***** SERVER RESTARTED *****","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-04T21:01:35.021-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-04T21:01:35.027-07:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-04T21:01:35.027-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-04T21:01:35.028-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":58706,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/Users/my_username/homebrew/var/mongodb","architecture":"64-bit","host":"SC-*"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-04T21:01:35.029-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.0","gitVersion":"563487e100c4215e2dce98d0af2a6a5a2d67c5cf","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-04T21:01:35.029-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"17.7.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-04T21:01:35.029-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"config":"/Users/my_username/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf","net":{"bindIp":"127.0.0.1"},"storage":{"dbPath":"/Users/my_username/homebrew/var/mongodb"},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"/Users/my_username/homebrew/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-04T21:01:35.038-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"/Users/my_username/homebrew/var/mongodb","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-04T21:01:35.038-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=7680M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress,compact_progress],"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-04T21:01:36.177-07:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22347,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version. This may be due to an unsupported upgrade or downgrade."}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-04T21:01:36.178-07:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":28595,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Terminating.","attr":{"reason":"45: Operation not supported"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-04T21:01:36.178-07:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":28595,"file":"src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp","line":1100}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-04T21:01:36.178-07:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

Can i please seek your help in fixing this? I am not having sudo rights and can't upgrade the OS, but am  open to use mongo using any method

Comment: What version did you upgrade from?

Comment: I upgraded it to _4.4_ and it should be _4.2_ from which i upgraded.  I also checked with `brew services list` command and it is not green but yellow. Can I seek further help if possible. I also tried lower versions like _3.6_ and _4.0_, but i am getting same behavior.

Comment: Actually your log has nearly exactly the output it would have when you simply forget to set feature compatibility. I can tell because I also just forgot it on an upgrade from 4.2 to 4.4... And for that case @Eddy's answer is correct.

Answer (score 6):

similar issue, final worked solution:

1. uninstall (latest, but not worked version: `4.4.3`)

`brew uninstall mongodb-community`

2. reinstall, old but worked `4.2.1`

`brew install mongodb-community@4.2`

3. run

- for now: `brew services run mongodb-community@4.2`
- for now and set bootable: `brew services start mongodb-community@4.2`

4. check status

`brew services`

Answer (score 4):

The log is telling you what is going on

```
"Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version. This may be due to an unsupported upgrade or downgrade."
```

So you may want to read documentation of your old mongoDB version to see if it is upgradeable to version 4.4.0, if it is not, consider upgrading to a most recent version that is compatible with the WiredTiger version you are currently using

This [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.0-upgrade-standalone/) might be useful. To upgrade to mongoDB v4.0 or above you must be running at least mongoDB v3.6, otherwise you will have to to upgrade to v3.6 first

Comment: tl;dr `db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "4.2" } )` for a 4.2 to 4.4 upgrade which was installed before 4.2: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/setFeatureCompatibilityVersion/

Answer (score 0):

uninstall mongodb
remove /var/lib/mongodb/  # because WiredTiger was not uninstalled cleanly
reinstall mongodb

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue it occurred when my mongodb docker container restarted. What I did was remove mongod.lock its in the root folder where database data is stored.

Try the following steps:

first copy your database folder to be sure you have a backup.

then execute the following command:

```
mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair
```

check now if it works, if it still does not work

try to temporarily move the mongod.lock to some other location to test if the mongod.lock is causing the issue. Start mongodb and check if it works. If it does not you should downgrade.

To downgrade to the correct version you can do the following:

```
bsondump mongo/diagnostic.data/metrics.2021-10-06T08-41-05Z-00000  | jq -s '.[] | select(.type == {"$numberInt": "0"})| .doc.buildInfo.version'
```

Keep in mind that the metrics file can have a different date this is just an example.

After you have the version you can start your container with that specific version and it should work.

Comment: Thank you!  After the repair step, I restart MongoDB and it works.