# MongoDB keeps crashing due to WiredTiger related error

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I've set up a Docker container using both Flask and MongoDB to make a web service. However, when it's time for MongoDB to set up, this batch of errors keeps appearing:

```
mongodb          | {"t":{"$date":"2020-09-19T10:04:23.524+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
mongodb          | {"t":{"$date":"2020-09-19T10:04:23.526+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
mongodb          | {"t":{"$date":"2020-09-19T10:04:23.526+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
mongodb          | {"t":{"$date":"2020-09-19T10:04:23.527+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":1,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"d77da017e32d"}}
mongodb          | {"t":{"$date":"2020-09-19T10:04:23.527+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.0","gitVersion":"563487e100c4215e2dce98d0af2a6a5a2d67c5cf","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu1804","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
mongodb          | {"t":{"$date":"2020-09-19T10:04:23.527+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"18.04"}}}
mongodb          | {"t":{"$date":"2020-09-19T10:04:23.527+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"net":{"bindIp":"*"}}}}
mongodb          | {"t":{"$date":"2020-09-19T10:04:23.533+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=483M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress,compact_progress],"}}
mongodb          | {"t":{"$date":"2020-09-19T10:04:24.042+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":17,"message":"[1600509864:42697][1:0x7f1f6ebe4a80], connection: __posix_open_file, 806: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists"}}
mongodb          | {"t":{"$date":"2020-09-19T10:04:24.046+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"unexpected file WiredTiger.wt found, renamed to WiredTiger.wt.30"}}
mongodb          | {"t":{"$date":"2020-09-19T10:04:24.050+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":1,"message":"[1600509864:50093][1:0x7f1f6ebe4a80], connection: __posix_open_file, 806: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted"}}
mongodb          | {"t":{"$date":"2020-09-19T10:04:24.074+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":17,"message":"[1600509864:74624][1:0x7f1f6ebe4a80], connection: __posix_open_file, 806: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists"}}
mongodb          | {"t":{"$date":"2020-09-19T10:04:24.079+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"unexpected file WiredTiger.wt found, renamed to WiredTiger.wt.31"}}
mongodb          | {"t":{"$date":"2020-09-19T10:04:24.083+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":1,"message":"[1600509864:83783][1:0x7f1f6ebe4a80], connection: __posix_open_file, 806: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted"}}
mongodb          | {"t":{"$date":"2020-09-19T10:04:24.111+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":17,"message":"[1600509864:111131][1:0x7f1f6ebe4a80], connection: __posix_open_file, 806: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists"}}
mongodb          | {"t":{"$date":"2020-09-19T10:04:24.116+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"unexpected file WiredTiger.wt found, renamed to WiredTiger.wt.32"}}
mongodb          | {"t":{"$date":"2020-09-19T10:04:24.121+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":1,"message":"[1600509864:121046][1:0x7f1f6ebe4a80], connection: __posix_open_file, 806: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted"}}
mongodb          | {"t":{"$date":"2020-09-19T10:04:24.123+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22347,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version. This may be due to an unsupported upgrade or downgrade."}
mongodb          | {"t":{"$date":"2020-09-19T10:04:24.123+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":28595,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Terminating.","attr":{"reason":"1: Operation not permitted"}}
mongodb          | {"t":{"$date":"2020-09-19T10:04:24.123+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":28595,"file":"src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp","line":1100}}
mongodb          | {"t":{"$date":"2020-09-19T10:04:24.123+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
mongodb exited with code 14
```

For reference, here's my `docker-compose`:

```
version: '2'
services:
    mongodb:
        image: mongo
        restart: always
        container_name: mongodb
        ports:
        - 27017:27017
        volumes:
        - ./mongodb/data:/data/db
    flask-service:
        build:
            context: ./flask
        restart: always
        container_name: flask
        depends_on:
        - mongodb
        ports:
        - 5000:5000
        environment:
        - "MONGO_HOSTNAME=mongodb"
```

Since I made it always restart, the database naturally does that, but I can't exactly figure out how to resolve this issue. From reading the errors, it seems like there's a problem with either permissions, or the WiredTiger installation. This also produces many zero-byte `WiredTiger.wt.#` files, one per attempt.

And here's also the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
MAINTAINER NAME EMAIL
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install flask pymongo flask_table
RUN mkdir /app
RUN mkdir -p /app/data
COPY service.py /app/service.py
ADD data /app/data
EXPOSE 5000
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT [ "python3","-u", "service.py"]
```

Comment: Could be this be of any help? https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/328

Comment: I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54911021/unable-to-start-docker-mongo-image-on-windows), but whenever I try it, no pages load from Flask, and the database doesn't accept any changes from my Python code.

Comment: had you tried by changing base image.

Answer (score 0):

#### simple answer

```sh
brew uninstall mongodb-community

brew install mongodb-community@4.2

brew services start mongodb-community@4.2
```

#### more

pls refer other posts's answer: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48381581/upgrading-older-mongo-database-after-unintentional-mongo-version-upgrade/65840273#65840273), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63750364/mongodb-community-not-starting-on-mac-and-giving-errors/65840251#65840251)